# How to share docker images among different machines in a cluster?

Tags: docker, image, cluster-computing

I've just started to maintain a cluster consisting of several machines. After deploying the kubernetes on each node, I found out that there is a tedious task for me to load docker images on each machines when I need to use some local mirrors.
So here comes the problem, is there any elegant way to spread mirrors among each nodes quickly?

At the moment, I just utilize docker save and docker load command to transfer the image files among these machines by scp.
I'd like to find out some way that enables me to do once and spread images to all nodes.
Try hard to search for the similar problems, but it seems I cannot get an existing solution for that.

Comment: Do you use ssh to do this.  There are several tools, like PSSH, that let you type a single command in multiple ssh sessions at once.

Comment: You could always set up your own docker registry, eg: https://adamtheautomator.com/private-docker-registry/ That would let you manage images with push/pull.

Comment: In a Kubernetes context, you wouldn't even need to manually pull things, the cluster will do it on its own if a Pod names an `image:` that doesn't exist locally.  I'd use `docker load` only as a last resort if you actually _can't_ use or run a registry, like in a physically isolated network.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It works by setting up my own registry on one of the machines.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to run a docker registry image inside one of these VMs and upload it to that. The other VMs, assuming they have network access to this VM which runs the registry can download from it.